# React Navigation Icon in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, styles, mobile-development

I use react-native-navigation to create the navigation in my project, and I need to put the image  instead of the icon and this is my code

```js
const startTabs = () => {
  Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
    tabs: [
      {
        screen: "awesome-places.Product",
        label: "first Icon",
        title: "first Icon",
        icon: require("../../../images/006-coffee-cup.png")
      },
      {
        screen: "awesome-places.Bag",
        label: "Icon",
        title: "Icon"
      }
    ]
  });
};
```

the result is like this with blue color! [image]

but the origion image like this : [image]

and I need to keep the color of the image, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

i think by default each icon selected, their background color will change also,
**"changes the color of all the non-transparent pixels"**

try to add **selectedIcon** with the same image:

```
const startTabs = () => {
  Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
    tabs: [
      {
        screen: "awesome-places.Product",
        label: "first Icon",
        title: "first Icon",
        icon: require("../../../images/006-coffee-cup.png")
        selectedIcon: require("../../../images/006-coffee-cup.png")

      },
      {
        screen: "awesome-places.Bag",
        label: "Icon",
        title: "Icon"
      }
    ]
  });
};
```